# How to upload TIGER shapefiles into MongoDB?

Tags: shapefile, tiger, mongodb

I have the school district shapefiles [from TIGER for Michigan](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2012/UNSD/tl_2012_26_unsd.zip), from:
ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2012/UNSD/

I'd like to use [MongoDBs geoquery features](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/) to interrogate this data.

How do I upload the .sh, .sh.xml, .dbf, .prj files into MongoDB so that I can execute these queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you want to store your ESRI Shapefiles in MongoDB. There are only [two ways](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#location-data) to store your data in MongoDB so that you might operate over them using the provided geospatial indices and queries: as GeoJSON Point, Line, or Polygon features, or as "legacy coordinate pairs." You probably want to store the same geographic features as a GeoJSON document. You can easily convert your Shapefiles to GeoJSON using [GDAL's ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html):

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output_features.json input_features.shp
```

Next, you'll need to use MongoDB's API to insert these documents into a collection. There's a [great number of client libraries to choose from](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/) for this purpose. Document insertion using any one of these APIs is very straightforward; [here's an example from the Python API documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert).